# Foursquare Autocomplete API explorer response different from android app response

Tags: android, foursquare

Using Get Autocomplete Results from Foursquare API with query="tor" I obtain the following response:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Toro",
        "secondary": "Search for Toro",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=Toro",
      "search": {
        "query": "Toro"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Torts",
        "secondary": "Search for torts",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=torts",
      "search": {
        "query": "torts"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Tortas",
        "secondary": "Search for tortas",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=tortas",
      "search": {
        "query": "tortas"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Tortillas",
        "secondary": "Search for tortillas",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=tortillas",
      "search": {
        "query": "tortillas"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Tortellini",
        "secondary": "Search for tortellini",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=tortellini",
      "search": {
        "query": "tortellini"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Tortilla chips",
        "secondary": "Search for tortilla chips",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=tortilla%20chips",
      "search": {
        "query": "tortilla chips"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Flour tortillas",
        "secondary": "Search for flour tortillas",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 6,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=flour%20tortillas",
      "search": {
        "query": "flour tortillas"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Toritos",
        "secondary": "Search for toritos",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=toritos",
      "search": {
        "query": "toritos"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "search",
      "text": {
        "primary": "Corn tortillas",
        "secondary": "Search for corn tortillas",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 5,
            "length": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/places/search?ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875&radius=5000&query=corn%20tortillas",
      "search": {
        "query": "corn tortillas"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "address",
      "text": {
        "primary": "1212 N White Ave Unit TORTOISE",
        "secondary": "Pomona CA 91768",
        "highlight": [
          {
            "start": 22,
            "length": 8
          }
        ]
      },
      "link": "/v3/address/US-5553415a00000d6ab0ba-TORTOISE",
      "address": {
        "address_id": "US-5553415a00000d6ab0ba-TORTOISE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, from android app, using the same query ("tor") I obtain this:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/5fc0ae16588d471e148fabdd",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/default_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"5fc0ae16588d471e148fabdd",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.501881,
                  "longitude":-81.655775
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"4502 Prospect Ave, Cleveland, OH 44103",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Torqhoist",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Torqhoist",
            "secondary":"4502 Prospect Ave, Cleveland, OH 44103"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/a72ee189bff540a9be1f76ae",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/salon_barber_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"a72ee189bff540a9be1f76ae",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.498648,
                  "longitude":-81.640991
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"2218 E 70th St, Cleveland, OH 44103",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Torbert Gentleman",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Torbert Gentleman",
            "secondary":"2218 E 70th St, Cleveland, OH 44103"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/4e2f55dbb61c88c3a7978004",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/default_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"4e2f55dbb61c88c3a7978004",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.486285,
                  "longitude":-81.703027
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"1849 W 24th St, Cleveland, OH 44113",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Tortilleria La Bamba",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Tortilleria La Bamba",
            "secondary":"1849 W 24th St, Cleveland, OH 44113"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/97af915a6bc04bf0316a74e0",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/lawschool_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"97af915a6bc04bf0316a74e0",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.504925,
                  "longitude":-81.690684
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"1301 E 9th St, Cleveland, OH 44114",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Kenneth A Torgerson Aty",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":10
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Kenneth A Torgerson Aty",
            "secondary":"1301 E 9th St, Cleveland, OH 44114"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/38b9f5f36a0341246f32b963",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/default_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"38b9f5f36a0341246f32b963",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.520917,
                  "longitude":-81.661465
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"4700 Lakeside Ave E, Cleveland, OH 44114",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"An Invitations to Remember",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               
            ],
            "primary":"An Invitations to Remember",
            "secondary":"4700 Lakeside Ave E, Cleveland, OH 44114"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/d88b94ee789d46a5e54e2e5a",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/gas_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"d88b94ee789d46a5e54e2e5a",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.488457,
                  "longitude":-81.652401
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"5307 Woodland Ave, Cleveland, OH 44104",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Hanini Subs/El Toro At Marathon",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":15
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Hanini Subs/El Toro At Marathon",
            "secondary":"5307 Woodland Ave, Cleveland, OH 44104"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/cac8208930cc43a1eee5fba7",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/lawschool_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"cac8208930cc43a1eee5fba7",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.483822,
                  "longitude":-81.703503
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"2012 W 25th St, Cleveland, OH 44113",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Jazmin Torres Lugo Law Offices",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":7
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Jazmin Torres Lugo Law Offices",
            "secondary":"2012 W 25th St, Cleveland, OH 44113"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/c8bc36e82d3e4c5ad390919e",
         "place":{
            "categories":[
               {
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/default_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "fsq_id":"c8bc36e82d3e4c5ad390919e",
            "geocodes":{
               "main":{
                  "latitude":41.485555,
                  "longitude":-81.727095
               }
            },
            "hours":{
               "display":""
            },
            "location":{
               "country":"US",
               "formatted_address":"1369 W 59th St, Cleveland, OH 44102",
               "locality":"Cleveland",
               "region":"OH"
            },
            "name":"Torres \u0026 Sons Detective Services",
            "photos":[
               
            ],
            "popularity":0.0
         },
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Torres \u0026 Sons Detective Services",
            "secondary":"1369 W 59th St, Cleveland, OH 44102"
         },
         "type":"place"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/search?ll\u003d41.515899658203125%2C-81.68150329589844\u0026radius\u003d5000\u0026query\u003dToro",
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Toro",
            "secondary":"Search for Toro"
         },
         "type":"search"
      },
      {
         "link":"/v3/places/search?ll\u003d41.515899658203125%2C-81.68150329589844\u0026radius\u003d5000\u0026query\u003dtorts",
         "text":{
            "highlight":[
               {
                  "length":3,
                  "start":0
               }
            ],
            "primary":"Torts",
            "secondary":"Search for torts"
         },
         "type":"search"
      }
   ]
}
```

Both Foursquare Explorer API and the app are showing a 200 response with the url being:
https://api.foursquare.com/v3/autocomplete?query=tor

Answer (score 0):

the responses are different because the latitude and longitudes (ll) for each call is different.

link": "/v3/places/search?**ll=39.085296630859375%2C-77.64520263671875**&radius=5000&query=Toro",

"link":"/v3/places/search?**ll\u003d41.515899658203125%2C-81.6815032958984**4\u0026radius\u003d5000\u0026query\u003dToro"

This is usually derived from IP address but can be provided as a param in the API calls. The API is trying to auto-complete addresses closer to request first. Check out the API explorer for more details.
https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/autocomplete-1

Comment: Interesting. one response was from the Get Autocomplete Result API explorer (the one you linked), and the other is from android virtual device. Both are using the same Wifi.

Comment: Is it possible the android virtual device is spoofing IP?

Comment: I ran a "where is my ip location" on a chrome webpage from the virtual device, and I got a matching location.